# アンドロイドスタジオのbuild.gradleでの設定

Tags: android-studio, build

アンドロイドスタジオのbuild.gradleでの設定に関してです。

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation"org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:Sanko_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

こちらの最後の一文、が

> This detector looks for usages of libraries where the version you are using is not the current stable release. Using older versions is fine, and there are cases where you deliberately want to stick with an older version. However, you may simply not be aware that a more recent version is available, and that is what this lint check helps find

と、問題がある。と出てしまいます。
どうやら以前のバージョンと最新のバージョンが違うせいで、問題がでているようなのでバージョンをそろえようとしました。
support libraryとバージョンを合わせるとよいみたいなのでsupport library　を確認しようとしても、入っていませんでした。
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup?hl=ja
こちらのサイトを参考にAndroid Support Repositoryまではいれることができました。
しかし、ここからの解決策がわかりません。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]